# (R) My matrix is coming out inversed

Tags: r

I have a data frame that I want to turn into a matrix, however when I use this code:

`df11 <- matrix(df10$Numbers,nrow=5,ncol=12)`

The matrix comes out where the first five data points are in column 1, the next 5 are in column 2 etc. I want the matrix to have the first 12 data points in row 1 and the next 12 data points in the second row, etc.

Could anyone help me? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: use `byrow=TRUE` in the `matrix` call

Comment: Thank you so much akrun!